# linq join 3 tables with or condition

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, join

I need to create a statement in LINQ with 3 tables and OR condition.

My function receives an integer, lets call it `intZ`. I have 3 tables: `tableA`, `tableB` and `tableC`.

`tableA` has columns `int1`, `int2` and `intB`. `intB` is related to `tableB`.

**problem:** `int1` or `int2` of `tableA` can be `intZ` and it has to match with one `tableC` record.

I need an OR condition, but I have no idea where to place it. Does it go in the where clause? Or in the equals clause?

At the moment, I know how to join 3 tables, but the condition is killing me.

What is the difference between the two ways to create statements in linq? Is there a performance impact?

edit: Okay, now I think it's more clear. `intZ` has to be related with `intC` from `tableC`, and this number can be `int1` or `int2` of `tableA`.

[image]

Comment: Its easier to help you if you write down your SQL query so we know how to build a linq expression. Regarding the 2 ways to create statements there are no differences it is just matter of which one you feel more comforable with.

Comment: the query i created its wrong as i didnt use tableC, that why i didnt put it.

Comment: What does "atm i how hot" mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add it to a `Where`. In Linq2Sql this will be translated to an inner join (with or) on tableB

```
from a in tableA
from b in tableB.Where(x => x.A == a.A || x.B == a.B)
select new { a, b };
```

Comment: i never used this type of query statement on linq. what is the x? i saw this before but i dont know the same so i can read more about it. can u show me a link or a name? thx

Comment: x is a row in tableB (but only inside there where clause) I use it to join with table a on columns A OR B

Comment: con u provide me the name of this type of query? its has different structure from the one im being using. thx

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an "or" condition in joins in LINQ, as it only supports equijoins. But you should be able to do it in a `where` clause with no problems. For example:

```
var query = from rowC in tableC
            where rowC.intC == intZ
            from rowA in tableA
            where rowA.int1 == rowC.intC || rowA.int2 == rowC.intC
            join rowB in tableB on rowA.intB equals rowB.intB
            select new { rowA, rowB, rowC };
```

Comment: the tableC comes in a 3rd join i suppose, where i have to match intz == tableC.id or rowA.int1 == tableC.id or rowa.int2 == tableC.id. how should u put tableC.id in this?

Comment: @GuillermoVarini: Sorry, it's still really clear how all of this is meant to hang together. It would be clearer if you could give a *full* example, ideally with more meaningful names than `int2` etc.

Comment: ok, its has a picture now and check where its says edit: i think now is much more clear.

Comment: @GuillermoVarini: Okay, have a look now. Looks like it should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful.

```
var locations = from r1 in 
          (from a in context.A
          join b in context.B
          on a.ID equals b.ID
          select new
          {
            a.Prop1,
            a.Prop2,
            b.Prop3,
            b.ID
          })
          join c in context.C
          on r1.ID equals c.ID
          select new
          {
            r1.Prop1,
            r2.Prop2,
            r2.Prop3,
            c.Prop4
          };
```

Answer (score 1):

For the life of me, I couldn't get the .Where to work in my query (perhaps it's how I'm using LinqPad) but I was able to get the following to work:

```
from s in Stores
join a in Areas on s.AreaID equals a.ROWID
join r in Regions on a.RegionID equals r.ROWID
join e in Employees on 1 equals 1     // <-- produces a cartesian product
join t in Titles on e.TitleID equals t.ROWID
where e.AreaID == a.ROWID || e.RegionID == r.ROWID // <--filters the data based on OR stmt
where s.StoreNum == 469
select new { r.RegionName, a.AreaName, s.StoreNum, s.StoreName, t.JobCode, e.FirstName, e.LastName }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var result= tableA.SelectMany(a => tableB.Where(x => x.A == a.A || x.B == a.B), (a, b) => new {a, b});
```